# Why is "in" missing from “... kick-start a party soccer style ...”?

Tags: prepositions, headlinese, compounds

> Times Life tells you how to kick-start a party **soccer style** as the FIFA World Cup 2014, in Brazil, gets underway.

Source - Times of India

I understand the meaning of this sentence, but I think there should a ***in*** before the bold part. Why is it omitted?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it is missing an 'in'.. `soccer style` should be in parenthesis.  Either that or it should be moved to before `party`... `a soccer-style party`

Comment: Soccer-style should be hyphenated. It's a compound adjective.

Comment: It's a compound adverb (see below), not a compound adjective. The customs for hyphenation are less clear for compound adverbs. In this context, often the hyphen is omitted. See, for example, the section titled "Compound Adverbs" in [this book](http://j.mp/Unl1qj).

Answer (score 3):

The phrase `soccer style` is functioning as an adverb modifying `kick-start`.

#### Explanation

In English, it is fairly common to use a noun as an adjective to modify another noun. That's what's happening with `soccer`: it's being used as an adjective to modify `style`.

Using `style` together with a modifier as a modifier for something else is a fairly common idiom in English. So, the phrase means "kick-start a party in the style of soccer". Another example is "a hot dog prepared [Mexican style](http://j.mp/1oAWVD5)". There, `Mexican style` is a compound adverb modifying `prepared`. Sometimes criminals are said to "kill someone [execution style](http://j.mp/1n1gcKZ)", that is, as if performing an execution. A recently famous example of this idiom is [Gangnam Style](http://j.mp/1hIBXlx). This use of the word `style` fulfills a role similar to that of the French preposition `à`; English lacks a preposition with that meaning.

You can look up "attributive noun", "compound adjective", and "compound adverb" if you're curious to get more information.

Comment: Is there any link for further study in compound adverb? Because I want to learn more about this topics. I mean to say there should be some rules as to which words can be used as adverbs like this and which doesn't. I believe we can't use all words as adverbs like this. So I need to learn at least that much. Can anyone help?

Comment: A couple minutes of googling didn't turn up anything especially thorough or authoritative. You'll probably find the best information under "attributive noun". [This article](http://j.mp/1uHHLxA) seems OK, though it says very little specifically about compound adverbs.

Comment: I also googled and found nothing of value regarding compound adverb. Actually this compound adverb is something that is new to me. You can tell me how to decide which word to use as adverbs like this and which don't. Thank you for the link.

Comment: In English, it's only a slight exaggeration to say that any word can be used as any part of speech. A word's grammatical role depends enormously on context. A big factor, though, is that when a word commonly forms a phrase, like `style` in "American style", "royal style", "Texas style", "Gujerati style", etc., phrases with the same word in the same place in the phrase are easier to perceive as a single unit, and thus easier to use as compound modifiers. There is no "rule", though.

Comment: But if we write "style" alone like this "Start the party in style", there is a need of "in", without which it's incorrect. The problem arises when we add something with "style" like "american style". And in the last instance the "in" becomes optional.

Comment: This might help a tiny bit: It's actually fairly uncommon for an attributive noun phrase to serve as a compound adverb, simply because there aren't all that many _meanings_ of attributive noun phrases that make any sense as modifiers for verbs or adjectives. Theoretically, "kitchen cabinet" (`kitchen` is a noun functioning as an adjective modifying `cabinet`) could be used as an adverb, but I am stumped to think of a verb that it could modify. Maybe this is why the `style` idiom stands out.

Comment: The phrase "in style" actually has its own, idiomatic meaning. It means "in high style" or "in very good style". This is why you can't omit "in" in that case. I've never thought about this before, so I might be wrong, but I think if you're abusing only a single word as an adverb rather than a phrase like "_x_ style", you can't get away with omitting the preposition. It would just be too unclear.

Comment: @BenK - If you consolidated these comments into a single answer, I think it would be a pretty good answer. Either way, though, I appreciate you being helpful to the OP, ELL style.